# jquery: how to detect element that is being loaded every few seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a div element where a file is being loaded every 10500 miliseconds;

index.php

```
...
<div class="loadHere"></div>
...
```

code that loads every few seconds.

```
setInterval(
function ()
{
$('.loadHere').unload().load('filetoload.php').fadeIn('slow');

}, 10500);
```

filetoload.php

```
<a href="#" class="testbtn">test</a>
<input type="hidden" value="1234" class="hiddenelement"/>
```

and this is what i'm trying to do but isn't working:

```
$(document).on('click','.testbtn',function(event)
{
      event.preventDefault();

     var xyz = $('.hiddenelement').val();

    alert(xyz);


});
```

Comment: What are your expectations?After clicking on test you are just alerting value of hidden element

Comment: @amol I am going to let it scroll to that element with that id..
but right now. .even an alert isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your strategy seems to work.

```
setInterval(
function () {
   $('.loadHere').unload().load('toload.php').fadeIn('slow');

}, 10500);


$(document).on('click','.testbtn',function(event)
{
  event.preventDefault();

 var xyz = $('.hiddenelement').val();

alert(xyz);
});
```

Here is the working plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/tiLv3WMDCjoW3Ggb9bTH?p=preview.

Comment: hmmm.. that's strange.. Maybe it has something to do with the rest of my code which is in php... =/

Answer (score 0):

Use Callback function:

```
$( "#success" ).load( "/not-here.php", function( response, status, xhr ) {
  if ( status == "error" ) {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
  }
});
```

From [Jquery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/)